# Increment integer daily in PHP

Tags: php

Starting with a base number of 1000. How would I add 100 everyday to the base number?

Output every 24 hours would be:

- 1100 day 2
- 1200 day 3
- 1300 and so on...

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? `+=` comes to mind, not sure where the number is stored though

Comment: Hi, this question isn't very clear. Do you need this number to be stored somewhere, with some method to reset the number? Or just to calculate the number of days from some fixed start date? Is the output on a web page that can be accessed at any time, or does it need to be sent somewhere?

Comment: Which date does the base number start from? If it's a fixed date (say 13/09/2018 = 1000) then it shouldn't actually be particularly hard to calculate today's number. Something like: `days_since_start_date * 100 + 1000`

Comment: @MartinParkin the start date would be today. The number doesn't need to be stored anywhere. I get I can simply do this `{{1000 + 100}}` but not sure how to do it everyday

Comment: As I already suggested, work out how many days have occurred since today, multiply that by 100 and add to 1000.  It shouldn't be too difficult to achieve -> Google: days between dates php

Comment: Just be careful to compare _date_ to _date_, unless time (hh:mm:ss) matters.

Comment: @echo A server won't remember that "today" means "13th September 2018"; to a computer, "today" means "date the program is running"; so you need to store the start time somewhere. Either you store the number (e.g. in a database), and every day add to it and write it back; or more simply, you write a function which compares "time the program is running" to "13th September 2018". Either way, you need to do some research, try something, and come back with a more specific question if you're having problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for

```
$startday = new DateTime('2018-09-12');
$today = new DateTime();
$days  = $today->diff($startday)->format('%a');

echo $value = 1000 + $days*100;
```

Comment: I don't think you need the `date('Y-m-d')` in there, because the `%a` is always going to return a whole number of days anyway, so you can just do `$now = new DateTime();`

Comment: @echo Checked the above solution?

Comment: There's no need to pester the asker of the question; the system will do that, and it's up to them to read it.

Comment: @IMSoP sorry. I was not aware of it. I thought he missed it

Comment: No worries, but it's good to be patient - 10 minutes is no time at all on a site like this. If you click on a user's name, you can see [their profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3669657/echo) which includes a "last seen" timestamp. In this case, you can see that the user hasn't been seen on the site since you wrote this answer, so hasn't yet had a chance to read your answer.

Comment: @RinsadAhmed thanks for the help. That worked great!

Comment: If we echo $days only then also it will give expected output.